# How to add manual new Wi-Fi connection on Ubuntu 19.10?

Tags: 19.10

I like to ask you about "How to add manual new Wi-Fi connection on Ubuntu 19.10?". On Ubuntu 16.04 I found a button, but in 19.10 I can't find it.
 [image]

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting.html.en is an excellent guide for 19.10 .

Answer (score 0):

Use the command `nm-connection-editor`.

Click the **+** button at the bottom of the window.

Select **Wi-Fi** from **Hardware..** and then click **Create...**.